Merge two docx documents using Apach poi or other lib with Java
I need to merge two ore more docx documents into one;
All examples here works only with body of documents, just concatenate several xml into one.
But it's not working with other parts of dicument: images, styles, numbering etc.
Does any one decided propblem with full merging docx documents?
Problem with classic merging with Apach poi described in this comment:
Merging two document and convert to pdf - APACHE POI
